# How do allow to use a scope only to admin users with a certain value in Rails 4 model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, scope, has-scope

In my recent Rails project I have a scope in a model. This scope has two possible values: true or false.

```
scope :ultima, -> ultima { where(:ultima => ultima )
```

I´m using has_scope gem to allow using this scope in controller so I can do calls like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/model?ultima=true
```

or

```
http://localhost:3000/model?ultima=false
```

In this project, I have normal users and admin users who have special access to some parts of the application.

How do you allow to use this scope with value 'false' to admin users; but when value is 'true' is allowed to everyone?

Answer (score 0):

I generally use Rolify and Pundit to accomplish this.  Rolify sets :admin on the model.  And pundit has a scope where i check if user is :admin.

You can also do this through a namespace and have a separate admin controller that you lock this down with.